# How to filter files in the generated test coverage report by EMMA, using Ant in Android

Tags: android, ant, code-coverage, emma

I have an Android project and I am correctly generating test coverage reports using Ant and EMMA (I did it by following the instructions here: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+an+Android+app+and+test+project)

What I would like to know is **how can I filter the files that appear in the report generated by EMMA** (for example, the R generated classes, files in an already tested library...).

I included both ${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/test_rules.xml and ${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/main_rules.xml in my own build.xml file and there I tried to change the "-emma-instrument" target to look like that:

```
<target name="-emma-instrument" depends="compile">
    <echo>Instrumenting classes from ${out.absolute.dir}/classes...</echo>
    <!-- It only instruments class files, not any external libs -->
    <emma enabled="true">
        <instr verbosity="${verbosity}"
               mode="overwrite"
               instrpath="${out.absolute.dir}/classes"
               outdir="${out.absolute.dir}/classes">

               <filter excludes="*R*" />
        </instr>
        <!-- TODO: exclusion filters on R*.class and allowing custom exclusion from
             user defined file -->
    </emma>
</target>
```

I also tried to apply another variations of EMMA coverage filters specified here http://emma.sourceforge.net/reference_single/reference.html#instrset.filters, but that does not work either, and the R generated files still appear in the coverage report.

Anybody knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Update: Filtering is built in as of revision r18 of the android SDK, just see my answer to the linked question.

There is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360972/ho-can-i-use-filter-for-emma-when-building-android-test-with-ant) asking for this, where you've been already the half way down the road. To solve your issue just make sure, that you do **not modify the test projects build file, but the one of the target project**. I've got really no clue what kind of ant magic is involved in the android app build files, but of course to some extend your target projects build file must play an important role, so it's kinda logical that you've got to specify the coverage modification within the target project.

It took me the whole morning to sort this thing out, so I hope it's of some value for other developers.

As a side note, this functionality should be [built-in as of revision 16](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21345) of the SDK tools.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I had the filter set on my test build.xml.