# How can I use filter for emma when building Android test with ant for a library project?

Tags: android, ant, android-library, emma

From this question :

[How can I use filter for emma when building Android test with ant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360972/how-can-i-use-filter-for-emma-when-building-android-test-with-ant)

I know emma can use a filter by adding the following lines to my ant.properties of the targeted project, not the test project,

```
emma.filter=-com.your.excluded.package.*
```

but it seems it doesn't work properly if my target project is a library project.

My workspace looks like this:

```
projectlib1         : lib project using lib2
projectlib1/tests   : unit tests for lib1
projectlib2         : lib project using lib3
projectlib2/tests   : unit tests for lib2
projectlib3         : stand alone lib
```

When I run coverage for lib1 I also get coverage files for lib2 and lib3 which I do not want.
Where should I add the emma.filter?
I tried putting it at the root of each of those projects but it did not work so far.

any suggestion welcome!
thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just had the same problem, I tried the solution of the thread you mention and I did not work.
I also tried to add it directly in the build.xml file, did not work either.

Although I managed to make it work by adding the `-Demma.filter="-your.app.package"` on the ant command line:

```
ant -Demma.filter="-your.app.package.to.exclude.*" emma debug install test
```

Comment: thanks! I tried that )I think with the -D at the end) with no luck, but this time it worked perfectly. So, thanks.